# Is this an anonymous Object being returned Here?

Tags: java, android, interface, callback, overriding

I am going through the Android code on the camera tutorial. I come from a C#/Obj-C/Swift language set, so Java is still new to me. I am familiar with functional programming but this syntax I am seeing does not seem functional in nature (or maybe I'm wrong).

This is the code:

```
 button.setOnClickListener
        (
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                    }
                }
        );
```

The line `new View.OnClickListener()` is what I am stuck on. OnClickListener is an Interface. So my question is this: **is new View.OnClickListener() creating an anonymous object which has OnClickListener interface, and overriding the onClickView?**

P.S. If you could also give me the Java name of what this 'type' code is I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the call to `new View.OnClickListener() {...}` instantiates an object of an anonymous type that implements `View.OnClickListener`. The name of this class would be determined by the name of the **surrounding class**, and will take the form `SurroundingClass$index`. So if this is the first anonymous inner class in `MyClass`, it will be called `MyClass$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it creates an anonymous class that has implemented the method. Check this out: [Anonymous classes Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)